# asp.net telerik radWindow icon size

Tags: asp.net, telerik, icons, size, radwindow

I'm facing a trouble with a RadWindow, from the Telerik Library. I'm adding Telerik in my asp.net project through DLLs and when **I try to load an icon in the top left part** of the window, it doesn't display anything.

After searching for a bit, **I found that the size of my icon was the source of my miseries**. I'm trying to load 128x128 icons where the width and height of my RawWindow icon is set to 16x16 in the css file.

Now my question : How can I manage to change the **width and height of my RadWindow's icon** ? I have subclassed RadWindow so I could write some CSS in my code-behind, but after trying for a while, I can't manage to find a way to do it !

I also tried to write some css code in my website default css file, without much success neither!

Can somebody provide me a solution to this please ?

Answer (score 0):

Your title seems to indicate that you have an issue setting the icon size; however your question seems to indicate that your issue is really how to set the window size. If the latter, then this should do it:

Client-side, you can use [`setSize`](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/window-programming-radwindow-methods.html)

```
wnd.setSize(400, 400);
```

And [server-side](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/window-programming-server-side-properties.html) you can use Width, Height, etc.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I edited the question... I want to change the icon allowed size that goes into the left part of the window... At the moment, I can't put only 16x16 icon in the top left icon... I want to be able to put 128x128 icons as well ! Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @AndyM: I know you are not looking for homework, but if you look at this: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/window-appearance-css-classes-usage.html you should get an idea on what CSS classes you need to modify in order to have your icons display what you want. Worst case scenario, you should be able to find the damn css selector for the icon and use jquery to force it to whatever you want.